# A code generator for java available for maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, code-generation

I am developing a java project with maven which generates code files. I am looking for a good code generator that is available for maven.

So far I tried

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.tikal.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tikal-maven-jet-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
```

The advantage of this plugin is that it generates the generator during the build cycle and does not add any runtime dependencies. However, I could not test it because I could not find a maven repository to download it.

So which code generator should I use? (Or where can I find a working tikal repository?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which code generator should I use? (Or where can I find a working tikal repository?)

I don't know what "code generator" you're looking for exactly but the tikal-maven-jet-plugin has its own repository:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>tikalk-repository</id>
    <url>http://network.tikalk.com/release/repository/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  ...
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Thank you for the repository. I just generally want to know some good code generators.